# Centering a images within absolute positioning for 3 responsive columns

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center an image (the "Coca" of Coca Cola in my fiddle example) that is within an absolute element `.itemDisplay` which has no fixed width.

I believe the no fixed width is and issue as it seems to stop the image from centering.

There are alot of answers for centering within a absolute element but I can't find any that are for multiple columns rather than just the left 50%, etc answers. `.itemDisplay` sits within a div called `.parentItem` that is 32% of the screen with some padding and margins and there are 3 per row.

All 3 column will have it's own image, but I've only done the first one as an example.

When the div containing the coca image is hovered it currently displays a hidden div with cola with the image centered which works correctly, my only issue is centering the coca image.

I have tried all answers and can't seem to get it to work.

Any ideas!?

https://jsfiddle.net/se23vvwu/

Comment: some people use the css transform property for this.

Comment: @Brian do you have an example that would work in this case? I have tried myself and with an answer on another question and the closest it's got to centering with transform has been literally centered on the screen rather than centered within it's 33% div.

Answer (score 0):

Your parent elements need to be relative and have the size of it's children. For that, if you can't have a fixed width, you can use `width: fit-content;`.
Then I applied `left: 0; and right: 0;` for the absolute element.

Here is the result (you still need to accomodate the hover state):

```
#shopShelves {
width : 100%;
padding : 15px;
max-width : 100%;
margin : 0 auto;
}
.parentItem {
height : 200px;
background-color : #e7e7e7;
float : left;
margin-left : 1px;
margin-bottom : 1px;
position: relative;
}
.parentItem a {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: inline-block;
}
.parentItem:hover .hoveredItem {
opacity : 1;
z-index : 1;
}
.parentItem:hover .itemDisplay {
opacity : 0;
}
.I33 {
width : 33.2%;
}
.displayCenter {
position : relative;
width : 33.2%;
background-color : #F00;
}
.parentItem:hover {
opacity : 1;
}
.itemDisplay {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0s 0.2s;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: fit-content;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.hoveredItem {
opacity : 0;
margin-bottom : 0;
}
.imgcenter {
display : block;
margin : auto;
max-width : 280px;
float : none;
position : relative;
}
```

`width: fit-content;` has some compatibility issues with IE. But I'm pretty sure there are workarounds. Some people use `display: table;`

More browser specific properties:

```
  width: intrinsic;           /* Safari/WebKit uses a non-standard name */
  width: -moz-max-content;    /* Firefox/Gecko */
  width: -webkit-max-content; /* Chrome */
```

You might have to do a little more research.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to do it with absolute rather than relative as the relative takes up the space and pushes down the hover, rather than letting the hover go over it's space if that makes sense? Is it possible to use fit content with absolute positioning?